# android animation : fading out a view and move the views under it to fill it space using smooth animation

Tags: android, animation

In my layout i have 3 views that are laid vertically above each other

```
view1 
view2
view3
```

if the user click on view1 it should fade out and when the fading is finished view2 and view3 should move up to fill it place smoothly
i know how to make the fade out animation for view1  and i know that there is a listener to indicate that the animation is finished  but i can't move view2 and view3 up to fill the remaining space smoothly . maybe its a simple question and maybe posted before but i cant find it . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Animation animationPrevious = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.//ur animation type comes here//);
view.startAnimation(animationPrevious);
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can try:

```
view1.startAnimation( /* your animation */ );
view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```